# Why 'sudo service networking restart" do not work?

Tags: networking

Normally, if I run `sudo service networking restart`, it will take some time before it finishes.

But, on one machine, it returns immediately, and the results in ifconfig does not change even when `/etc/network/interfaces` is changed. Then I have to restart the machine in order to load any changes in the `interfaces` file.

I'm wondering how to debug this problem.

My OS is ubuntu server 13.10.

Comment: Are you using Network Manager, and what happens if you run `sudo service network-manager restart`?

Comment: It says "network-manager: unrecognized service". My OS is ubuntu server 13.10.

Comment: Server edition does not use Network Manager. `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` should reset the networking based on the `interfaces`file.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks for user **douggro** (comment from Mar 9 '14 at 22:05)!

Answer for me was:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```